# Kivy different type of coordinates

Tags: layout, coordinates, kivy

I try to under stand the different types of coordinates:

1. Global,
2. Local,
3. Window and
4. Widget

coordinates.

using the program:
    class TargetUI(BoxLayout):

```
js_type = NumericProperty(0)

def __init__(self, **arg):
    super(TargetUI, self).__init__(**arg)
    btn1 = Button(text='Hello world ' + str(self.js_type))
    self.add_widget(btn1)


def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    # here, you don't check if the touch collides or things like that.
    # you just need to check if it's a grabbed touch event
    Logger.info("in touch up")
    Logger.info("global coordinates: " + str(touch.pos))

    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):

        touch.push()
        # if the touch collides with our widget, let's grab it
        touch.grab(self)
        Logger.info("In widget " + str(self.js_type))

        touch.apply_transform_2d(self.to_local)
        Logger.info("Local coordinates " + str(touch.pos))
        touch.apply_transform_2d(self.to_window)
        Logger.info("Windows coordinates " + str(touch.pos))
        touch.apply_transform_2d(self.to_widget)
        Logger.info("Widget coordinates " + str(touch.pos))
        touch.ungrab(self)

        # and accept the touch.
        return True


class CombWidget(Widget):
     pass

class MyPaintApp(App):   
    def build(self):
        return CombWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
     MyPaintApp().run()
```

and

```
#:kivy 1.7.1

<CombWidget>:
tg1: tg1
tg2: tg2
tg3: tg3

    BoxLayout:
       size: root.size
       orientation: 'vertical'
       padding: 20

    TargetUI:
                    js_type: 1
        id: tg1


    TargetUI:
                    js_type: 2
        id: tg2


    TargetUI:
                    id: tg3
        js_type: 3
```

All the coordinates written out by on_touch_up is the same, but expected some difference. Why are are all the coordinates the same?

I also expected to see the Button text to end with 1,2 or 3 but their are all 1. How can I make the Button text be depended in self.js_type?

Comment: Would you mind saying if my answer is helpful or not? If it is, upvote and/or mark it as accepted?

Comment: it was helpful thanx, I cant upvote. Did accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are useful when there are coordinate changes. For example, with the scatter widget, here is an example where one of the widgets is put in a Scatter and you can move it (somehow it gets back in place when you click it again, but it's convenient). When you do that, you should see that the coordinates are no longer the same. understanding the difference between them is left as an exercise to the reader :)

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
GridLayout:
    cols: 2
    spacing: 10
    ClickBox

    Scatter:
        ClickBox:
            pos: 0, 0
            size: self.parent.size

    Widget:
        ClickBox:
            pos: self.parent.pos
            size: self.parent.size

<ClickBox@Widget>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    on_touch_move:
        if self.collide_point(*args[1].pos): print self.to_window(*args[1].pos)
        if self.collide_point(*args[1].pos): print self.to_parent(*args[1].pos)
        if self.collide_point(*args[1].pos): print self.to_widget(*args[1].pos)
        if self.collide_point(*args[1].pos): print self.to_local(*args[1].pos)
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runTouchApp(Builder.load_string(kv))
```

Answer (score 1):

The Documentation for [RelativeLayout](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html#parent-coordinates) clarified this issue for me.

> Parent coordinates
>
> Other RelativeLayout type widgets are Scatter, ScatterLayout, and
>   ScrollView. If such a special widget is in the parent stack, only then
>   does the parent and local coordinate system diverge from the window
>   coordinate system. For each such widget in the stack, a coordinate
>   system with (0, 0) of that coordinate system being at the bottom left
>   corner of that widget is created. Position and touch coordinates
>   received and read by a widget are in the coordinate system of the most
>   recent special widget in its parent stack (not including itself) or in
>   window coordinates if there are none. We
>   call these coordinates parent coordinates.

So you must use one of the above special widgets for local coordinates to diverge from window coordinates. Tshirtman's answer works because he used the scatter widget which is one of the special widgets.